# Checking the Specific Minutes and Seconds in Moment.js

Tags: reactjs, momentjs

When a user selects an end day on my calendar component, I have the following:

```
moment(currentTime.end).endOf('day').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Usually the date range is preset but users can also adjust the time range within the date range.

If a user sets the end time to 23:59:59, I want to add an additional second and give them 24 hours. Is there a way in moment.js to recognize when a certain date set to the `endOfDay`, and is there a way to add a second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> use `.add(1, 'second')` to add a second
>
> use `.format('HH:mm:ss') === '23:59:59` to check is time end of day

e.g.:

```
var currentTime = {start: xxx, end: xxx};

// get the endTime by HH:mm:ss
var endTime = moment(currentTime.end).format('HH:mm:ss');
if (endTime === '23:59:59') {

    // If true add one second and return the format you need
    endTime = moment(currentTime.end).add(1, 'second').formet('YYYY-MM-DD');

} else {

    // If false just return the format you need
    endTime = moment(currentTime.end).formet('YYYY-MM-DD');

}
```